# Customizing windows terminal

Tags: terminal, colors

How to make my own color scheme in windows terminal ? More specifically : **What is the proper format of making a color scheme ?**

A little explanation :

Lets take this scheme for example :

> ```
> {
>     "name" : "Campbell",
>
>     "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
>     "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
>
>     "background" : "#0C0C0C",
>     "foreground" : "#CCCCCC",
>
>     "black" : "#0C0C0C",
>     "blue" : "#0037DA",
>     "cyan" : "#3A96DD",
>     "green" : "#13A10E",
>     "purple" : "#881798",
>     "red" : "#C50F1F",
>     "white" : "#CCCCCC",
>     "yellow" : "#C19C00",
>     "brightBlack" : "#767676",
>     "brightBlue" : "#3B78FF",
>     "brightCyan" : "#61D6D6",
>     "brightGreen" : "#16C60C",
>     "brightPurple" : "#B4009E",
>     "brightRed" : "#E74856",
>     "brightWhite" : "#F2F2F2",
>     "brightYellow" : "#F9F1A5"
> },
> ```

Terms like `name`,`cursorColor`,`selectionBackground`,`background` and `foreground` are kind of self-explanatory but what about the sequence of colors after it ?!! Are they written in any order ? What will change if i change `brightRed`{3rd line from bottom} to some other color ? I cannot find any articles answering my queries. Thanks in advance !!

Some related articles i already searched to get some help :

[customize-settings/color-schemes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/color-schemes)

[customize-settings/profile-settings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The later colors represent what color is used when text is outputted in these colors. Although you should not change the name, you can change the color value after it.

Once done, you can test it by writing: `write-host "this is a test" -foregroundcolor "red"` or whatever color you've changed, to see the result.

This is done, so you can change the background and foreground color, then fix whatever color that is used in functions that output to the screen, to display correctly against the new colors.

Their order does not matter, you can even remove them so the default value is used, but its easier to keep them there. Also, it may be possible to add "Orange" and change this color. Write-Host does not support the color orange, but it is used when creating a warning using: `write-warning "some warning"`

Given that since Windows 10 2015 the command prompt now also supports ANSI color changing, I'm positive this will also affect cmd commands using those colors too.

Answer (score 0):

What will change if i change brightRed{3rd line from bottom} to some other color ?

I refer to your question

brightRed{3rd line from bottom} This line is for the main text color in the terminal
It is white by default ps c:\ XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
You can change it to any hex color you like eg brightRed{#03fc2c} color is green

https://github.com/SG-studi0/windows_terminal_theme.git
colorful windows terminal theme

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1141257)